# ngrok tunnel not returning the control to the caller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, webhooks, ngrok

I am not sure the title of the posting truly describes my issue but here is what's happening, in more details. I have an ASP.Net MVC application that redirects to a page hosted in an external system. This external hosted page is used to enter the details of a credit card in order to process a payment. Once the payment is processed, the hosted payment page is sending an HTTP POST to a webhook URL which was provided by me, when the transfer to the HPP was made. I have a Web API controller in my ASP.Net MVC application and this will be used to receive the webhook call. Now, to test it while I am running everything locally, I had to use ngrok to create a private tunnel between the HPP and my local Web API endpoint.

I have a breakpoint in my Web API controller and I am getting the data sent by the HPP, data that contains details about the approved payment. The controller responds with an HTTP 200 which I see it in the ngrok console:

[image: ngrok Console page]

For some reasons, this HTTP 200 is not propagated back to the HPP which should display a back button to yield control back to my web application where we all started in the first place. Instead, the browser is directed to an URL which is the exact URL for the webhook, the one that was provided when the transfer to the HPP is made:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? Is the ngrok not returning the HTTP 200 back to the caller, which is the hosted payment page?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

TIA,
Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is not an issue with ngrok. The remote Hosted Payment Page (HPP) is not sending an HTTP POST to a RESTful endpoint, as I erroneously assumed. Insted it is returning to a specified URL and sends the response as hidden fields.

So if anyone is ever facing the same situation, please make sure you understand exactly the behaviour of the remote server. This could send the response as an HTTP POST sent to a specified URL or could yield the control back to your application by means of navigation where the response is send as hidden fields (HTTP POST with content of type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").